# What is the technological basis for Azure DocumentDB?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, document-database, nosql

Microsoft announced the availability of Azure DocumentDB as follows...

```
A fully-managed, highly-scalable, NoSQL document database service.
- Rich query over a schema-free JSON data model
- Transactional execution of JavaScript logic
- Scalable storage and throughput
- Tunable consistency
- Rapid development with familiar technologies
- Blazingly fast and write optimized database service
```

I really like the "transactional execution of JavaScript logic".
Sounds like an approach similar to that of PostgreSQL NoSQL.

Anyone know what is the technological basis for the Azure DocumentDB service? SQL Server?

Comment: This isn't really a question for SO. And is going to attract opinionated answers

Comment: I'm sorry to disagree. The question is objective and answerable (what is the technical basis) and is related to development (I am really looking at this as an alternative).
Also, looking at http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask I could not find anything against questions that "might attract opinionated answers".

Comment: @user1703840 - it's not a programming question. You're asking about implementation details. And it's not an opinion-based question either, as simonmorley suggested, since there's no opinion about it - it's a document database-as-a-service. Fortunately a member from the docdb team actually posted an answer here (definitively stating this is not based on SQL Server). That said: This question doesn't fit here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

DocumentDB has been built from the ground up as an entirely new database specifically designed for JSON and one that has deep integration with JavaScript. 
It does not share anything with SQL Server.

Comment: it is an answer. it answered the question of whether this was based on SQL Server. The answer is no.

Comment: It's not really a question for SO either.

Comment: SO isn't the place for questions that will attract opinions or are generally subjective. Or aren't programming related. You're best trying to answer decent questions otherwise your answers are likely to get down voted :(

Comment: so it is better to leave the question unanswered then? #seriousquestion

Comment: Probably still better to answer the question. (IMO, an offtopic question warrants downvotes on the question, not on answers)